# React Data Table Pagination showing but not working

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I'm using the **pagination** from `react-data-table-component`.
But it's unclickable although it's showing. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
return (
    <div>
      <DataTable
        title="Inventory"
        columns={columns}
        data={products}
        direction="auto"
        fixedHeaderScrollHeight="500px"
        pagination
        style={{ display: "flex" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you need to add more data into it, in your case you just have 6 data. CMIIW

Comment: I tried 100 datas and it’s also not working.